# Java Swing Customize Controls

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, custom-component

I want to know how to create a new Swing Control.

My problem resides on the lack of some components on Swing(datepicker for example)

I looked over Stack Overflow(and some others sites) and found some *old* answers but without success(several links doesn't work anymore).

So could you point me in some direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very large number of components you can use in your application. Google will help you finding them. An example for a datepicker is [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) and [Java Swing Date Picker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datepicker/). Just download it, add the jar to your application and use it. You could easily add it as a bean to the palette of your IDE and drag and drop it like a JButton. JCalendar has also a JDayChooser, JYearChooser a couple of spinner beans and a JLocaleChooser. I have been using Kai Toedter' JCalendar a few years and recommend it highly. Localization is simple.

If you want to create your own controls you must create them as Java Beans. The objects must be serializable, have a no argument constructor and accessors and mutators named set, get and is. An old but nice article on JavaBeans is in [Java-World](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1997/jw-08-beans.html?page=1). You can study JCalendar's Java sources.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Swing component from scratch is a lot of work, so it's probably easier to try to find something on the web first.

For many use cases *composing* different Swing components is a good solution. All Swing components can contain sub components, for example adding a browse button to a JTextField is fairly easy.

If you really want to go through with creating a whole new control, perhaps this article might give you a boost:

**[How to Write a Custom Swing Component](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx), which sets out to address some of those missing components you've noticed in core Swing!

Believe me, you do *not* want to implement your own DatePicker. SwingX has one (the JXDatePicker), it works pretty well, take a look at the article [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) for more.